How can I call a function expecting `params T[]` arguments given an `IEnumerable<T>`?
How can I call a function expecting param T[] arguments given an IEnumerable<T>?
Consider the following function signature:
public async Task AddNotificationRecordsAsync(
               IEnumerable<NotificationRecord> notificationRecords,
               CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)

In this function, I want to call the following EF Core function:
void DbSet<NotificationRecord>.AddRange(params NotificationRecord[] entities)

However, I don't know how to convert the IEnumerable into separate params.
In Python, I would use the unpacking operator "*" as follows: f(*mylist).

There is a DbSet<TEntity>.AddRange (IEnumerable<TEntity> entities); method, why did you have to call the other one?

Stop thinking in python. It will lead you into dark alleys. A lot of those apis have different overloads and most of them that take a "bunch" of items take IEnumerable<T>. The params T[] overload is basically syntactic sugar, so you don't explicitly need to create a collection first, if you just have a small amount but > 1 of items.


How can I call a function expecting param T[] arguments given an IEnumerable?

The param keyword allows you to pass an array as separate parameters. But it does not prohibit you to pass a regular array.
This is demonstrated in this example:
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    static void f(params int[] vals)
    {
        foreach (int val in vals) Console.Write(val + ",");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        f(1, 2, 3);  // works
        f(new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }); // also works
    }
}

Live demo
Therefore you can use Enumerable.ToArray method to convert IEnumerable<T> to T[] and pass it to a method expecting a param T[]:
public async Task AddNotificationRecordsAsync(IEnumerable<NotificationRecord> notificationRecords, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
   // ...

   //---------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--
   DbSet<NotificationRecord>.AddRange(notificationRecords.ToArray());
}

A side note:
In this specific case, as @shingo commented, DbSet<TEntity>.AddRange also has an overload that accepts IEnumerable<TEntity>. Therefore you could have passed notificationRecords as is.
